# Case insensitive compare against bunch of strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, compare, case-insensitive

What would be the best method to compare an NSString to a bunch of other strings case insensitive? If it is one of the strings then the method should return YES, otherwise NO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a little helper function:

```
BOOL isContainedIn(NSArray* bunchOfStrings, NSString* stringToCheck)
{
    for (NSString* string in bunchOfStrings) {
        if ([string caseInsensitiveCompare:stringToCheck] == NSOrderedSame)
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Of course this could be greatly optimized for different use cases.

If, for example, you make a lot of checks against a constant bunchOfStrings you could use an `NSSet` to hold lower case versions of the strings and use `containsObject:`:

```
BOOL isContainedIn(NSSet* bunchOfLowercaseStrings, NSString* stringToCheck)
{
    return [bunchOfLowercaseStrings containsObject:[stringToCheck lowercaseString]];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was especially looking for something like caseInsensitiveCompare:

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a few additions to Nikolai's answer:

`NSOrderedSame` is defined as 0

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NSComparisonResult) {NSOrderedAscending = -1L, NSOrderedSame, NSOrderedDescending};
```

So if you call `caseInsensitiveCompare:` on a `nil` object you would get `nil`. Then you compare `nil` with `NSOrderSame` (which is 0) you would get a match which of course is wrong.

Also you will have to check if parameter passed to `caseInsensitiveCompare:` has to be not nil. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/caseInsensitiveCompare:):

> This value must not be nil. If this value is nil, the behavior is
>   undefined and may change in future versions of OS X.